# Dimenson reduction from a cosine similarity matrix

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, mathematics, embeddings, tsne

I have a silly little question:

I have 200 press articles (string), I vectorize these articles with an embedding model (sentence embedding), so I have 1024 values per article.

I then have a 200 x 1024 matrix (vec_posts), and I calculate the cosine similarity between all these vectors (with scikit learn's cosine_similarity)

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

cos_emb = cosine_similarity(vec_posts, vec_posts)
```

I get a cosine similarity matrix of 200 x 200 (cos_emb)

Finally, I reduce the dimensions in this way:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE


scaler = StandardScaler()
cos_emb_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(cos_emb)

pca = PCA(n_components=.99, random_state=42)
cos_emb_pca = pca.fit_transform(cos_emb_scaled)

tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=42)
cos_emb_tsne = tsne.fit_transform(cos_emb_pca)
```

And I use a scatter plot to visualize.

I wonder if what I'm doing is mathematically correct? In a way, each item is characterized by the similarity between all the others.

I'd like to hear your opinion on this.

Comment: Have a look at the wiki page for [multidimensional scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling).